# Makefile Weird Errors Printing Variable Definitions

Tags: makefile, architecture

I'm getting a very mysterious "unsupported ARCH" error when I try to print out variable definitions in GNU Make 4.1.

The context is a very large collection of Makefiles which include each other and compile a long list of targets and global variables (it's the cyanogenmod android build tree).

I've added a target to the end of one of the Makefiles:

```
2273 .PHONY: showvars
2274 showvars:
2275    $(foreach v, $(.VARIABLES), $(info $(v) = $($(v))))
```

The output of make showvars is:

```
ALL_MODULES.TtsEngine.INTERMEDIATE_SOURCE_DIR =  /elements/Data/Android/android-source/out/target/common/obj/APPS/TtsEngine_intermediates/src
ALL_MODULES.sound.BUILT =  /elements/Data/Android/android-source/out/target/product/d851/obj/EXECUTABLES/sound_intermediates/sound
..
..
ALL_MODULES.CMFileManagerTests.MAKEFILE =  packages/apps/CMFileManager/tests/Android.mk
build/core/Makefile:2275: *** Unsupported ARCH .  Stop.

#### make failed to build some targets (01:36 (mm:ss)) ####
```

How could the printing of variables cause an architecture error? Or is ARCH the next variable name, but then what does the error mean?

EDIT:
I added $(info $(.VARIABLES)) to the end of the same Makefile. This command completes without error and the list of variable names is about 3 megabytes! of text. 305 of the variables contained the word "ARCH". But they all printed fine. An hour and many runs later (each make takes over a minute to run), and the answer is...

Function definitions!  if v is the name of a function, then $($(v)) runs that function. Different functions generate various interesting error messages. Here is the source of the ARCH error message, which came from the function define-libcompiler-rt-source-files, which coincidentally showed up in my original test immediately following a variable name that contained the word ARCH.

```
define get-libcompiler-rt-source-files
  $(if $(findstring $(1),arm),$(call get-libcompiler-rt-arm-source-files),
      $(if $(findstring $(1),mips),$(call get-libcompiler-rt-mips-source-files),
          $(if $(findstring $(1),x86),$(call get-libcompiler-rt-x86-source-files),
             $(if $(findstring $(1),x86_64),$(call get-libcompiler-rt-x86_64-source-files),
                 $(if $(findstring $(1),x32),$(call get-libcompiler-rt-x86-source-files),
                    $(if $(findstring $(1),arm64),$(call get-libcompiler-rt-arm64-source-files),
                       $(if $(findstring $(1),mips64),$(call get-libcompiler-rt-mips64-source-files),
  $(error Unsupported ARCH $(1)))))))))
endef
```

So, is there a way to get a list of all defined functions so that I can filter them out of variable list?

Comment: You can add `$(info $(.VARIABLES))` outside the rule, to see what that variable contains. Then you can use that to prepare a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Edited the question thanks. The quest for a minimal complete example led me to the explanation, though I'm still looking for a solution.

Comment: I know of no way to filter functions out of a list (a function is just a variable whose value conforms to a syntax), and I am unable to reproduce your error (GNU Make 3.8.1), but you could try `$(value $(v))` instead of `$($(v))`. Also note that `.VARIABLES` is a special variable, you can't assign values to it.

Comment: Yes, value does it! Prints out the functions beautifully. Thanks.